# Convert a text parameter to a powershell variable in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The following pipeline fails on the last line.
I need to convert a text parameter that can contains double quotes to a powershell variable.

```
parameters:
- name: text
  type: string
  default: test1 " test2

steps:
- checkout: none
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
          $messageText = "${{parameters.text}}"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a HereString instead of a normal string.

```
$messageText = @"
${{parameters.text}}
"@
```

Or single quote the code (it would then fail on single quoted things).

```
$messageText = '${{parameters.txt}}'
```

Or properly escape your double quotes with either doubling them, or preceding them with a backtick.

```
parameters:
- name: text
  type: string
  default: test1 "" test2

parameters:
- name: text
  type: string
  default: test1 `" test2
```

Or sanitize the input by escaping it in code (I've seen mixed results with this):

```
$messageText = "$('${{parameters.text}}' -replace '"','`"')"
```

Comment: The HereString solved my problem. Thanks...